# A listing of available PHP configuration options

Tags: php, configuration

Having browsed the net for a while, I've found that searching for a list of all the params available to add in the ./configure directive set when you make (compile) PHP is very hard to find since it will get you a lot of answers on how to use ini_set() and how to manipulate the php.ini file.

What I'm after - and it's probably available on the php.net site (which btw is one of the hardest sites to wrap your head around, navigation wise) - is a list / overview of what params are available and what they mean / do.

Just to avoid ambiguity, the params I mean are the ones used in a "configure" statement like so: (in PHP source folder) ./configure --enable-fpm --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-gd etc etc etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/configure.php

I haven't compiled PHP in awhile, but I thought there was either a -h argument or a README provided with the PHP source that listed and explained the available arguments for configure.

**Edit:**
This should get you a complete list of the available arguments

```
./configure --help
```

Comment: I feel like a moron not having found it myself. but you should know your help is greatly appreciated. Accepted your answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, there is a --help argument but like evrything else in unix it uses 10 words where 1 will suffice for anything that doesn't need 10 words where it uses 1.

Answer (score 0):

*Any* configure script will print out its options when called with the `--help` parameter:

> ```
> panther-g php-5.2.11 # ./configure --help
>
> `configure' configures this package to adapt to many kinds of systems.
>
> Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...
>
> To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...),
> specify them as VAR=VALUE. See below for descriptions of
> some of the useful variables.
>
> Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.
>
> Configuration:
> -h, --help              display this help and exit
> --help=short            display options specific to this package ...  
> --enable-sysvsem        Enable System V semaphore support  
> --enable-sysvshm        Enable the System V shared memory support  
>  --disable-tokenizer    Disable tokenizer support  
> --enable-wddx           Enable WDDX support
> --disable-xml           Disable XML support  
> --disable-xmlreader     Disable XMLReader support  
> --disable-xmlwriter     Disable XMLWriter support
> ...
> --with-qdbm=DIR         DBA: QDBM support
> --with-gdbm=DIR         DBA: GDBM support
> --with-ndbm=DIR         DBA: NDBM support
> --with-db4=DIR          DBA: Berkeley DB4 support  
> --with-db3=DIR          DBA: Berkeley DB3 support
> --with-db2=DIR          DBA: Berkeley DB2 support  
> --with-db1=DIR          DBA: Berkeley DB1 support/emulation  
> --with-dbm=DIR          DBA: DBM support
> ...
> ```

If you need specific extensions (like gd, for example), just look at the [extension's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/image.setup.php).

Comment: Yes. Noted. Thanks, but like I wrote above in my comment, and also proven so elegantly by your paste here, the --help isn't saying anything. Look at it. --enable-wddx and the explanation is..... "Enable WDDX support". That's just not right.